# Scenarios where Azure Web Role restarts itself

Tags: azure

I noticed that for some reason one of the web role stopped and restarted itself. Could someone help me to understand on what scenarios does the webrole restarts itself?

And, is there any way to find why the webrole restarted itself?

Answer (score 4):

That happens once in a while when Azure performs guest OS upgrades - it stops instances honoring upgrade domains and then starts them shortly thereafter. This is the most frequent scenario, the same could happen if the server hosting the VM was diagnosed faulty, but that happens quite rarely.

You should be ready for such restarts - they are normal - and your code should be designed to be able to continue working after such restart.

[Here's a post with more details on the upgrade process](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2012/09/19/role-instance-restarts-due-to-os-upgrades.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to find why the webrole restarted itself?

Comment: @Myagdi: AFAIK it's impossible, to you it will look that it "just restarted".